# How to get the contact information from specified uri of the contact

Tags: android

How can i get the total information from specified uri of the contact.

i am getting phone number, email address, name.
But i want what ever the information in that uri .

Elaborately, suppose Contact1 have name , ph no, email, address, group, etc..
 and

Contact2 have name, phno, email, business phn no and image,

How to write common code to get the Contact1 and Contact2.

Comment: read about the contact API in android : http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/contacts.html - also if you google "android get contacts programatically" there are tons of examples which are enough create what you need.

Comment: hi,thanx for replay, i can get the details of each column in the contact by using "getcolumnindex"   but i want to get the all info in particular contact.

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar, but I accomplished this by querying all the data by hand. I don't know of any Android built in class/function that returns an object that contains all the contact's information. I think you will have to build an object like this yourself by querying all the different fields (phone numbers, email addresses, contact specific information, etc.)

I hope this is helpful.